# How to change database name from default to custom in laradock?

Tags: php, docker, web, laradock

Everything is okay when I use default name. But when I change database name I can't   migrate. 
Here is my **mysql setting from laradock/.env**

```
### MYSQL #################################################

MYSQL_VERSION=5.7
MYSQL_DATABASE=dafault
MYSQL_USER=root
MYSQL_PASSWORD=root
MYSQL_PORT=3306
MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD=root
MYSQL_ENTRYPOINT_INITDB=./mysql/docker-entrypoint-initdb.d
```

And Here is my **mysql setting in .env** from project folder

```
DB_CONNECTION=mysql
DB_HOST=mysql
DB_PORT=3306
DB_DATABASE=default
DB_USERNAME=root
DB_PASSWORD=root
```

And here is my **docker-compose.yml** setting

```
## MySQL ################################################
    mysql:
      build:
        context: ./mysql
        args:
          - MYSQL_VERSION=${MYSQL_VERSION}
      environment:
        - MYSQL_DATABASE=${MYSQL_DATABASE}
        - MYSQL_USER=${MYSQL_USER}
        - MYSQL_PASSWORD=${MYSQL_PASSWORD}
        - MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD=${MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD}
        - TZ=${WORKSPACE_TIMEZONE}
      volumes:
        - ${DATA_PATH_HOST}/mysql:/var/lib/mysql
        - ${MYSQL_ENTRYPOINT_INITDB}:/docker-entrypoint-initdb.d
      ports:
        - "${MYSQL_PORT}:3306"
      networks:
        - backend
```

If I change any name from default

> php artisan migrate

doesn't work. Can you tell me what is the correct way to do this?

Comment: it says dafault on .env file not default

Answer (score 1):

What's the error message that you get when you migrate after db name change?

Anyway, you **MUST REBUILD** your mysql container after any .env changes, that could be done via the following command:

```
docker-compose build --no-cache mysql
```